# android detect touchstart on prototype js

Tags: javascript, android, prototypejs

i'm trying to make a magento extension work on android mobile devices. I bought this extension :

http://ecommerce.aheadworks.com/magento-extensions/layered-navigation.html

to get ajax layered navigation. It works well, but when it comes to android compatibility i get an issue on the range selector (slider selector, used for price range).

The feature works well on all device (ios included), but on android, i always got NaN instead of numbers values on the range selector. After digging the plugin's code, i found the origin in the javascript :

```
startDrag: function(event) {
    var isLeftClick = Event.isLeftClick(event);
    if (Prototype.Browser.IE) {
        var ieVersion = parseInt(navigator.userAgent.substring(navigator.userAgent.indexOf("MSIE")+5));
        if (ieVersion > 8) {
            isLeftClick = event.which === 1;
        }
    }
    if (isLeftClick || event.type === 'touchstart') {
        if (!this.disabled){
            this.active = true;

            var handle = Event.element(event);
            var pointer  = [Event.pointerX(event), Event.pointerY(event)];
            var track = handle;
            if (track==this.track) {
                var offsets  = Position.cumulativeOffset(this.track);
                this.event = event;
                this.setValue(this.translateToValue(
                    (this.isVertical() ? pointer[1]-offsets[1] : pointer[0]-offsets[0])-(this.handleLength/2)
                ));
                var offsets  = Position.cumulativeOffset(this.activeHandle);
                this.offsetX = (pointer[0] - offsets[0]);
                this.offsetY = (pointer[1] - offsets[1]);
            } else {
                // find the handle (prevents issues with Safari)
                while((this.handles.indexOf(handle) == -1) && handle.parentNode)
                    handle = handle.parentNode;

                if (this.handles.indexOf(handle)!=-1) {
                    this.activeHandle    = handle;
                    this.activeHandleIdx = this.handles.indexOf(this.activeHandle);
                    this.updateStyles();

                    var offsets  = Position.cumulativeOffset(this.activeHandle);
                    this.offsetX = (pointer[0] - offsets[0]);
                    this.offsetY = (pointer[1] - offsets[1]);
                }
            }
        }
        Event.stop(event);
    }
}
```

this line :

```
var pointer  = [Event.pointerX(event), Event.pointerY(event)];
```

return a correct array of value (mouse coordinates) on all devices, except on android, where i get NaN. Is this a known bug of prototype.js, and can I bypass it ?

thanks,

Comment: Are you using the latest version of PrototypeJS Framework, 1.7.2?

Comment: currently using prototype version 1.7.0, the version provided by magento

Comment: Ah then you can't change the version, as there was a fix that affected cumulativeOffset as well as a re-write of all the DOM methods in 1.7.1 and 1.7.2. Do you have a reduced version of the script that illustrates the problem so I can try a few things?

Comment: Thanks for the info, i'll see if i can upgrade safely my prototype version, i'd like to keep my libraries up to date and the point you're showing comfort me in this idea :). I don't have a reduced version of the script, but i found a hotfix for now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem solved by digging the event object, then manually retrieving the X and Y pos (tested clientX, screenX and pageX) :

```
var pointer  = [Event.pointerX(event), Event.pointerY(event)];
            if(navigator.userAgent.match(/Android/i)){
                pointer  = [parseInt(event.targetTouches[0].clientX),parseInt(event.targetTouches[0].clientY)];
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue, I know this is an old thread but want to post my solution anyway. I needed to override the functions in swiper.js.

```
    update: function(event) {
    if (this.active) {
      if (!this.dragging) this.dragging = true;
      this.draw(event);
      if (Prototype.Browser.WebKit) window.scrollBy(0,0);
      Event.stop(event);
    }
},
draw: function(event) {
    var pointer = [Event.pointerX(event), Event.pointerY(event)];
    if(navigator.userAgent.match(/Android/i)){
        pointer = [parseInt(event.targetTouches[0].clientX),parseInt(event.targetTouches[0].clientY)];
    }
    var offsets = Position.cumulativeOffset(this.track);
    pointer[0] -= this.offsetX + offsets[0];
    pointer[1] -= this.offsetY + offsets[1];
    this.event = event;
    this.setValue(this.translateToValue( this.isVertical() ? pointer[1] : pointer[0] ));
    if (this.initialized && this.options.onSlide)
      this.options.onSlide(this.values.length>1 ? this.values : this.value, this);
},
```

And this fixed my issue

Comment: To clarify: I did this in the var awLNControlSlider = Class.create(Control.Slider, { section